# How can I remove the "Enter character"(ascii=13) in the given string using this linux shell command?

Tags: string, shell

I want to use this linux shell command to remove the "Enter character"(ascii=13):
${variable//pattern/string}

My script is : 
${var//\n/}. It doesn't work.
So I change to ${var//\r/} and it doesn't work too.

So how should I write this script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use dollar expansion `$'\n'`:

```
${var//$'\n'/}
```

`$'\n'` expands to a literal newline. See [ANSI-C](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) quoting in the `bash` manual for more about this sort of expansion.

#### Edit

The above replaces newline, to replace carriage return use `$'\r'`:

```
${var//$'\r'/}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! But in my case, because the Enter character's ascii value is 13，I should write the script like this : ${var//$'\015'/}.

Comment: Ah missed you were talking about carriage return, updated answer.

Comment: Using $'\r' doesn't work. I have tried it. I find that the ascii value of \n is 110 and the ascii value of \r is 114. But in my case, the Enter character's ascii value is 13. So I must use $'\015'

Comment: Try this: `echo -n $'\n\r' | od -An -t o1`, I get: `012 015`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I am wrong. I use "echo -n \n | od -An -t dC" then I get \n ascii=110. Again I use "echo -n \r | od -An -t dC" then get \r ascii=114.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var=$(echo var | tr -d '\n')
```

to remove the newline. Or `var=$(echo var | tr '\n' ' ')` to replace it with a space.